# How to move the button which stays on tangent around the circle based on touches?

Tags: java, android, math, geometry, trigonometry

I have a circle that has a button on its tangent. 
I want to move that button around of circle, it will still stay on its tangent just the angle will change.
I can move it by changing angle, but how to move it based on touches onto screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find touch point angle relative to circle center and use it:

```
Angle = Math.atan2(touchpoint.y - circle.center.y, touchpoint.x - circle.center.x)
```

Comment: i'm trying the figure out the logic of what i wanted and your code. but it goes opposite way when i started to touch the area between 180 -270. is it because of sin?

Comment: I did not write about sin... atan2 is especially  intended to get angle in full range

Comment: okay,but how to update the angle after getting new angle, i used new angle = old angle + angle  , does plus or minus make difference ?

Comment: There is no need to update the angle - you just calculate it every time, and it is valid angle relative to center. If you mean something else - describe that in the question edit.